# OSC address without preceding slash (/)?

Tags: osc

I'm sending the following OSC message to a Behringer X32 mixer:

```
00000000  2f 6e 6f 64 65 00 00 00  2c 73 00 00 63 6f 6e 66   /node... ,s..conf
00000010  69 67 2f 63 68 6c 69 6e  6b 00 00 00               ig/chlin k...
```

I'm getting this message back:

```
00000000  6e 6f 64 65 00 00 00 00  2c 73 00 00 2f 63 6f 6e   node.... ,s../con
00000010  66 69 67 2f 63 68 6c 69  6e 6b 20 4f 46 46 20 4f   fig/chli nk OFF O
00000020  4e 20 4f 4e 20 4f 4e 20  4f 46 46 20 4f 4e 20 4f   N ON ON  OFF ON O
00000030  46 46 20 4f 46 46 20 4f  4e 20 4f 4e 20 4f 4e 20   FF OFF O N ON ON 
00000040  4f 4e 20 4f 46 46 20 4f  46 46 20 4f 46 46 20 4f   ON OFF O FF OFF O
00000050  46 46 0a 00                                        FF..
```

It seems that the address in the response is malformed as it does not begin with a preceding slash character `/`.

According to the [OSC 1.0 specification](http://opensoundcontrol.org/spec-1_0):

> An OSC Address Pattern is an OSC-string beginning with the character '/' (forward slash).

Is the packet I'm getting back from the mixer simply an invalid OSC message that I need to deal with, or is there some meaning or convention behind the omission of the slash character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in [Patrick-Gilles Maillot's unofficial documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/patrickmaillot/x32):

> Note/bug: the response from the Server is “node…” and not “/node…” as one could expect. This is not OSC compliant.